# Changing specific symbol of YII cactiverecord model's attribute

Tags: yii, cactiverecord

How to change specific symbol of YII cactiverecord model's attribute ?
Dont understand why it doesnt work:

```
echo $model->attr; // aaa
$model->attr[1] = 'b';
echo $model->attr; // aaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substr_replace` function:

```
echo $model->attr; // aaa
$model->attr = substr_replace($model->attr, 'b', 1, 1);
echo $model->attr; // aba
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Also you can use this approach:

```
$newValue = $model->attr[1] = 'b';
$model->attr = $newValue;
echo $model->attr; // aba
```

Your example does not work because actually `$this->AttributeName` execute `CActiveRecord::getAttribute('AttributeName')` [method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getAttribute-detail) and not affect original value.

Comment: Good answer. Basically, all CActiveRecord attributes are stored in an array, and accessed through magic __get() and __set() functions. Accessing string offset with brackets will not work in this case.